# Class instantiation in Dart and sharing code between Class objects

Tags: dart

When a class that contains code is instantiated, is the code is the class shared automatically by other instantiations of that same class? Eg. The data in the class that is instantiated may be minimal; however the code could be very significant. If the code is not "automatically" shared, is there a way to achieve that other than separating the code from the class data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Classes have the state and the behavior.

The state is encoded in member variables of the class. Each instance has its own copy of variables, thus its own state.

The behavior is specified by the methods implemented in the class ('methods' here stand for  all static, non-static methods, setters and getters). Implementation is shared by all instances of the class, so all instances behave the same, but actual results and side-effects depend on instance state, obviously.